# Haskell recursion of tail function

Tags: list, haskell, tail

I have this function

```
func1 :: Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> Maybe [(Double,Double)]
...............
func2 :: Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> [(Double,Double)]
func2 d [] =  []
func2 d list = 
  let dsegs1 = func1 d list
      dsegs2 = func2 d (tail list)
  in  fromJust dsegs1 ++ dsegs2
```

The simple flow I would like to achieve in `func2` is as follows:

```
let x = func2 3.0 list
let y = func2 3.0 (tail list)
let z = func2 3.0 (tail (tail list))
let a = func2 3.0 (tail (tail (tail list)))
```

call `func2` *n* times until it returns nothing at the end and concat `x`,`y`,`z`,..., `a`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `map (func2 3.0) (tails list)`.

Comment: thanks.. i solved it anyways but has 5 lines of code.. your one is so simple.. thanks man